# Partial derivative of double sum of cosine

Tags: partial-derivative

I have a problem calculating/verifying the partial derivative below:

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial{\phi_k}} \sum_{i=1 } ^{N} \sum_{j=1}^{N}\cos{(\phi_i-\phi_j})$$

My result, after doing the expansion for specific values of $i,j=1,2,3$  e.g., and generalizing , is the following:

$$-2\sum_{j=1}^{N}\sin{(\phi_k-\phi_j})$$

Could someone verify my result? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi Alex, i think i made the proper modifications in the fornula.

Answer (score 1):

You have:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial{\phi_k}} \sum_{i=1 } ^{N} \sum_{j=1}^{N}\cos{(\phi_i-\phi_j})$$
Which equals the following, tossing out all terms that have neither $i$ nor $j$ equal to $k$ and then accounting for the $(i,j)=(k,k)$ term which would otherwise be counted twice.
$$
\begin{align}
&\frac{\partial}{\partial{\phi_k}}  \sum_{j=1}^{N}\cos{(\phi_k-\phi_j})+\frac{\partial}{\partial{\phi_k}}  \sum_{i=1}^{N}\cos{(\phi_i-\phi_k})-\frac{\partial}{\partial{\phi_k}}\cos{(\phi_k-\phi_k})\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{N}-\sin{(\phi_k-\phi_j})+ \sum_{i=1}^{N}\sin{(\phi_i-\phi_k})-0\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{N}\sin{(\phi_j-\phi_k})+ \sum_{i=1}^{N}\sin{(\phi_i-\phi_k})\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{N}\sin{(\phi_i-\phi_k})+ \sum_{i=1}^{N}\sin{(\phi_i-\phi_k})\\
&=2\sum_{i=1}^{N}\sin{(\phi_i-\phi_k})
\end{align}$$

Comment: And since the sine function is odd, you can interchange the variables inside, and the result is the same right? And for index variable in the final result, j is also acceptable.